# Is there a way to 'tail -f' HID-Input of a buzz-controller?

Tags: linux, drivers, input, hid

I'm quite a linux-newb. I wanted to develop an application which communicates with Sony PS2-Buzzcontrollers via libusb but discovered that the linux-kernel already comes with out-of-the-box support for exactly that controller via

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-sony.c#L302

For example I can control the controllers leds via `echo 255 | tee /sys/class/leds/*buzz*/brightness`.

I was no wondering if there also is an easy way to listen to keypresses. Is there a file/folder/whatever those are called, that I might just `tail -f`?

As I am unaware about how those system-exposed interfaces are called I am having a hard time searching the web for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` I found that they are just ordinary input-devices.

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=054c Product=0002 Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:054C:0002.0008/input/input29
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 js0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=fffff 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: MSC=10
```

So to answer my question: One way would be to `cat /dev/input/event12`.

In hope for easier solutions, I'm leaving the question open a little bit longer.

For others who want to read more in depth about the linux-concept of those devices, the are called evdevicses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev